# Random characters displayed when printing array of characters

Tags: c++

This is my problem. I am reading a file in binary mode, appending the bytes to an int array, and printing the values after. My problem is, when I cout my results, random characters are being attached in the stream.

comp.txt:

```
this text is a testt1
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;

void read(ifstream& stream, unsigned int buf[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        unsigned char temp[4] = {'\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'};
        stream.read((char*)temp, 4);
        cout << "Temp: " << temp << '\n';
        buf[i] = *((int*)temp);     
        cout << "Read: " << buf[i] << endl;
        memset(temp, '\0', 4);
    }
}

int main()
{

    // open file
    ifstream f;
    f.open("comp.txt", ios::binary);
    cout << "File opened. " << endl;

    // get size
    f.seekg(0, ios::end);
    int l = f.tellg();
    int length = (l / 4) + 1;
    f.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    cout << "Size found: L: " << l << " Length: " << length << endl;

    // allocate byte arrays
    unsigned int* buf = new unsigned int[length];
    memset(buf, '\0', 4*length);
    // unsigned short* key = new unsigned short[length];
    cout << "Preparing to read..." << endl;

    // read byte into short
    cout << "Reading..." << endl;
    read(f, buf, length);
    f.close();
    delete[] buf;
    cin.ignore(1000, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\daminkz\Desktop>encrypt
File opened.
Size found: L: 21 Length: 6
Preparing to read...
Reading...
Temp: this
Read: 1936287860
Temp:  tex☺
Read: 2019914784
Temp: t is☻
Read: 1936269428
Temp:  a t♥
Read: 1948279072
Temp: estt♦
Read: 1953788773
Temp: 1
Read: 49
```

Things to note:

- temp is only 4 bytes, but 5 bytes are printed

Comment: An advice: don't rely on `int` being 32 bits wide. `#include <stdint.h>` and use `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you read in temp, you overwrite all 4 characters with data, leaving you without a NULL terminator. cout.operator<<(char*) expects a null-terminated string, so it's printing as many characters as it can until it reaches a null terminator. Making temp be 5 characters long, all '\0', but keeping number of bytes read at 4 will alleviate the problem.

Comment: Won't that cause problems when I deference temp and cast to buf[i]?

Comment: @Charles just don't convert four chars to an int by typecasting pointers, it's a Bad Thing. Use something like `buf[i] = temp[0] + (temp[1] << 8) + (temp[2] << 16) + (temp[3] << 24)`.

Comment: It probably won't cause problems, but as ulidtko said, you almost certainly don't want to do that. If you're reading integers in the same endianness as the system you're running on, read into the int directly or use bitwise operations to set the bytes of the integer manually. I witheld comment on the overall aesthetics of what you're doing, but there are better ways to read in binary data.

Comment: @ulidtko Care to explain exactly why it is bad?

Comment: @Charles Ray, it's bad because it's not portable. You have no guarantee as to sizeof(int) on the system you're going to be running at, and casting four bytes like that can cause elusive issues. This is also not endian-portable. Lastly (there are other reasons, but the ones I've mentioned should be convincing enough not to use it), this way isn't very clean and will be harder for other developers to get through.

Comment: @charles-ray It is bad because of dependency on too much platform-specific things, like endianness of integers on your system, and byte alignment of memory, and probably some other neat stuff. Though if you plan to ever use your program on just a single computer, this all doesn't matter and is just annoying buzzwords worth to be ignored.

Comment: Thank you for the description. More criticism is welcome. It's not supposed to be clean, however, as I am trying to implement my own encryption method.

Comment: Trying to implement your own encryption method is another flag that you should never, ever, ever do if you're writing code that is actually meant to protect data. If you're just dicking around, then by all means, but if you want strong crypto it's *never* a good idea to roll your own.

Comment: @charles-ray clean, easily maintainable source is always good. `;)`
If you'll keep your sources too dirty, they'll get bugs, and you will have real troubles getting rid of the beasts.

Comment: This is a learning example. If I wanted to actually encrypt something I would implement AES-256.

Comment: @ulidtko Your example worked, aside from you not typecasting the whole statement as an int. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are outputting temp as a null-terminated string, but it is not null-terminated, so you will print out 4 characters of temp and unknown number of garbage characters until you accidentally run into a 0.

Answer (score 1):

You're not null-terminating the buffer you're printing.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a char array to `cout` it gets converted to a char pointer, in other words what is normally called a "C-string". This means that to find the end of the string the output routing will search for the first `0x00` NUL character.

Your array is 4 chars however, and 4 chars are read from the file. If none of these is a NUL then the output will keep reading chars from memory until it finds one and that are the strange chars you're observing. Note that another possible result is a segfault because you're not supposed to be able to go around and read memory that you didn't explicitly allocate.

As a solution you could declare your array of 5 chars instead of 4, leaving the fifth always at NUL to be sure to stop the output.